# NativeScript Android Build throws error: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

Tags: javascript, java, android, angular, nativescript

I would like to build a NativeScript application for Android, but I'm stuck when trying to build the application using `tns build android` command.

I get this error: "Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1"
[image]

My NativeScript version is: 3.2.1

I've also set up the Environment Variables for both ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME:
[image]

and these are my Android SDK Platforms installed:
[image]

---

As @pkanev suggested, I've opened /.gradle/ and removed the wrapper directory. After that, I run `tns build android` again, but then it thrown me a new error:

'FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.'
'Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.'

Any thought on this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the gradle wrapper you got was corrupted. Delete your Gradle and let the android build redownload it.

Open `<User_dir>/.gradle/` and remove the `wrapper` dir.

Rerun `tns build/run android`

Comment: Thank you! I did that, now it throws a different error. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've managed to fix it by removing the whole `.gradle` folder from my `<User_directory>`, then I've built it again with `tns build android`.

Thank you @pkanev for your help!